# Elasticsearch mapping not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch

Having the following mapping:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/cambio_indice?pretty=true' -d '{
  "mappings" : {
      "el_tipo" : {
       "properties" : {
            "name" : { "type" : "string" },
            "age" : { "type" : "integer" },
            "read" : { "type" : "integer" }
}}}}'
```

If I add the following code it works perfectly even though it doesn't match with the mapping (`read` is missing) but ES doesn't complain.

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/cambio_indice/el_tipo/1?pretty=true' -d '{
    "name" : "Eduardo Inda",
    "age" : 23
}'
```

And if I add the following entry, it also works.

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/cambio_indice/el_tipo/2?pretty=true' -d '{
    "jose" : "stuff",
    "ramon" : 23,
    "garcia" : 1
}'
```

It seems that the mapping is not taking effect on the elements I'm adding. I'm doing something wrong when I try to map my type?

Comment: What is your expectation?

Comment: To fail when I put an entry, or show an error of `you are trying to add a propierty that is not mapped`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of Elasticsearch and is desirable in most of the cases. But for your case, if you do not want to allow indexing of fields not defined in your mapping, you need to update the mapping and set its `"dynamic"` property to `"strict"`. Basically, your mapping definition should look like below:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "el_tipo": {
      "dynamic": "strict",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string" 
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer" 
        },
        "read": {
          "type": "integer" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then if you try to index fields like "jose", "ramon" or "garcia", Elasticsearch will throw with an appropriate message saying that the dynamic addition of these fields is prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation Of ES:

> By default, Elasticsearch provides automatic index and mapping when data is added under an index that has not been created before. In other words, data can be added into Elasticsearch without the index and the mappings being defined a priori. This is quite convenient since Elasticsearch automatically adapts to the data being fed to it - moreover, if certain entries have extra fields, Elasticsearch schema-less nature allows them to be indexed without any issues.

So new fields added by you will get automatically added to your mappings.

See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/current/mapping.html#_automatic_mapping) for more info