# Elasticseach doesn't map all given fields [PHP]

Tags: php, elasticsearch, mapping

I'm working with Elasticsearch-PHP client. I want to index my datas, but I have a problem with mapping. There is a problem: I create my data array, everything works fine, but when I add this array to my index `body => my_data_array` some datas show up, but not all of them. I don't know why. I just digged and try all of following steps but nothing changed.

I just attached my snippets.

This my `controller` file where I index datas:

```
    {

    $params = ['body' => []];

    foreach($all_ads as $key => $ads){

        $params['body'][] = [
            'index' => [
                '_index' => 'demo_data',
                '_type' => 'demo',
                '_id' => $ads->id
            ]
        ];

        $params['body'][] = $ads->indexParams();

    }

    $responses = $client->bulk($params);
```

---

this is result json object:

```
"response": [
    {
      "id": 85345,
      "old_id": "5088063",
      "user_id": "2706",
      "category_id": "15",
      "type": "3",
      "title": array[3],
      "slug": "",
      "sub_region_id": "8",
      "condition": "1",
      "username": "John Doe",
      "price": "82000",
      "price_type": "1",
      "no_phone": "0",
      "views": "29",
      "hot": "0",
      "vip": "0",
      "price_measure": "0"
   }
```

I have a `data`field and it is not visible here.
Its `data` mapping structure

```
'data'          => [
    'type' => 'object',
    'properties' => [
        'key_id'   => ['type' => 'integer'],
        'value_id' => ['type' => 'integer'],
        'key'      => ['type' => 'keyword'],
        'value'    => ['type' => 'keyword']
    ]
]
```

How can I fix it?

I just check some question from here and github issue forum but nothing helps. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using dynamic or manual mapping? If you post you mapping structure here it would help a lot.

Comment: @Toni I use manual mapping. Maan, structure is too long, I fixed desciption, category, title field, Its my fault. But data field still doesn't show up. I just attache `data` structure here

Comment: You can create a public gist with mapping structure and paste a link here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow solution of the question. Its maybe helpful for you.

[Elasticsearch mapping not working as expected
Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35313080/elasticsearch-mapping-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: Thanks man for your response, but I tried this solution. Nothing changed :(